# Serial async write: How to add data to the output buffer & weird output buffer behaviour

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am using asynchronous serial write operation to send data. Using `fwrite()` I cannot send data if a write operation is already in progress. It returns an error:

```
Unsuccessful write: An asynchronous write is already in progress.
```

How can I simply add the extra data I need to write to the existing output buffer, instead of having to wait for it to finish?

Also, I tried to see the number of bytes left to output, but it would either show the full number (`511`, default size) or zero. So I increased the size of the output buffer to `100,000` sent that many items and plotted the `BytesToOutput`, this is what I got:

[image]

It drops from ~25,000 directly to 0!? Can anyone explain this please?

Here is my code:

```
instrreset; %closes, deletes and clears all available serial objects

s=serial('/dev/ttyACM0');
s.BaudRate= 1000000;
s.Timeout= 0.1;
s.OutputBufferSize= 100000;
fopen(s);

data=[1:99999];
bytesLeft=zeros(1,100000);

disp('sending data now... wait for it to complete')

tic()
fwrite(s, data, 'uint8', 'async');

f=1;
while ( strcmp(s.TransferStatus, 'write') )
    bytesLeft(f)=s.BytesToOutput;
    f=f+1;
    %disp(s.BytesToOutput)
end
toc()

plot(bytesLeft);

fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s;
```

Comment: If you initialize bytesLeft to 0 you will not know if the zeroes that you have come from s.BytesToOutput or if the loop ended and they are the initial values. Try initializing to -1. Also for Serial communication isn't 115200 the max speed? Can you do the changes and tell if it drops to 0 (which will come from s.BytesToOutput) or to -1 (which means that the loop has stopped)

Comment: Hi, the serial write can successfully handle high baud rates, I tested it on my logic analyzer. As for the bytesLeft, I will do that tomorrow and report back. Although, I am sure the result should be the same.

Comment: (i) when you initialise `data=[1:99999];`, you are creating an array of `double`, so the actual size at this time is 800,000 bytes to send. (ii) you start the write operation asynchronously, so there is absolutely no guarantee that there will be one byte written at each iteration of the `while` loop. So the preallocation of `byteleft`, while a good thing (to preallocate), is approximate only and could go out of bound.